# How to count these spikes?

Tags: arduino, analog, signal-processing, waveform

This signal is from an instrumentation amplifier,
read from Arduino MEGA2560 ADC,
loop delay 10ms (rate 100Hz)

I need to **count high spikes only**, (in below figure, 6 high spikes can be observed)

**Edited** -
**its and ECG signal and signal was sampled at a rate of 100Hz**

[image]

Comment: What does the frequency spectrum (FFT) look like? Can probably use a digital filter to get rid of the lower frequency shift.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this purely a software algorithm question? Oh and is that a heart rate waveform? If it is, then the algorithm can be made to expect something about the signal.

Comment: Looks similar to an EKG. Maybe you can use methods that are applied to those?

Comment: I would high pass it until it looks roughly level, and then count up each time the signal passes a fixed threshold.

Comment: @Justme i forgot to mention its ECG, i need the count only

Comment: What about high pass filtering it for a start.

Comment: yes, look at the first derivative.

Comment: @kobi89: If you are using a loop and a delay to time your sampling and the delay is 10 milliseconds, then you will be sampling no faster than 100 samples per second. (1 second divided by 10 milliseconds gives 100 samples per second.)

Comment: That agrees with your chart showing heartbeats at just over one per second, and the vertical grid lines spaced every 100 samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done by using some high pass filter to remove DC bias, then you differentiate the signal to detect high dv/dt. At each high dv/dt you set a flip-flop. If the FF is set you compare the amplitude threshold and you clear the FF when dv/dt becomes negative.

Comment: How to differential the signal?

Comment: The differential is : y(k) =( u(k)-u(k-1) ) / T_sample; Where u(k) is the actual sample and u(k-1) is the previous sample. Find some book about digital control, look for differentiation. Also you can scrape the D-part of some yet available PID algorithm for Arduino.